# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] returning correct value but not passing conditional

Tags: php, http-referer

I have a contact form and a product form. I want to check to verify there is product value ONLY on product form BUT I can get the conditional to pass.

**Broken Code**

```
// If visitor filled out the form on the "Contact Us" page (/contact/index.php) then no 'product' field is required.
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://www.url.com/contact/index.php" || "http://url.com/contact/index.php") {
    if(strlen($product) < 2) {
        $errors[] = "<font color='red'>Please enter the product requesting.</font>";
    }
}
```

**Troubleshooting / Debugging Code**

```
$serverValue = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
print "The value of SERVER is ". $serverValue;
echo "<br />";
print $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/contact/index.php";               
echo "<br />";

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://www.url.com/contact/index.php" || "http://url.com/contact/index.php" || "/home/url/public_html/contact/index.php") {
//if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/contact/index.php") { 
print "This is NOT the Contact page";
} else {
print "This IS the Contact page";
}
```

Troubleshooting / Debugging Output

> The value of SERVER is http://url.com/contact/index.php
>   /home/url/public_html/contact/index.php
>   This is NOT the Contact page

You can see by the output that the correct HTTP_REFERER is being passed but it just won't evaluate correctly. There is a commented out line in there where I was trying other things. Please go easy on me Im new at PHP.

Alright, I understood what I was doing wrong and tried this with no success

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://www.url.com/contact/index.php" || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://url.com/contact/index.php") { 
if(strlen($product) < 2) {
$errors[] = "<font color='red'>Please enter the product requesting.</font>";
}
}
```

Any other thoughts?

Comment: this isn't reliable to use

Answer (score 1):

It does evaluate correctly as a non-empty string evaluates to `true`.

So with:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://www.url.com/contact/index.php" 
   || "http://url.com/contact/index.php" 
   || "/home/url/public_html/contact/index.php") {
```

it does not matter what the first condition is because the second and the third always evaluate to `true`:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://www.url.com/contact/index.php" 
   || true 
   || true) {
```

Results in:

```
if (true) {
```

If you don't want the referrer to be any of these 3 strings, you can use something like:

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , [
    'http://www.url.com/contact/index.php', 
    'http://url.com/contact/index.php', 
    '/home/url/public_html/contact/index.php'
]) {
```